# ParentId not populating in ContentDocument

Tags: contentdocument

I am wanting to run a method when a certain kind of file is attached to an Opportunity. I've done this before by creating an attachment trigger.

Unfortunately, my client has enabled convert attachments to Salesforce files. I understand how to get info from the file to determine whether or not to call my method, I don't however have the reference to the opportunity.

The field ParentId on Content Document isn't populated. RelatedEntityId is the userId. If anyone know hows SF is relating the opportunity, I would be very grateful to know.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Besides @crmprogdev's  tips, here's some additional information that may help you

- `ContentDocument.ParentId` points at a library that owns the document when it was created. So, in your use case, you would not expect this to be populated
- The connection between the `Opportunity` and the `ContentDocument` can be found in the junction object `ContentDocumentLink` that has two lookup fields, one called `ContentDocumentId` and one called `LinkedEntityId` which points at the Opportunity.  Salesforce Files can be shared across multiple objects and hence the junction record.

Answer (score 1):

You want to be looking at the [ContentVersion](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_contentversion.htm) object. ContentDocuments are actually controlled by the ContentVersion which is the latest version of a [ContentDocument](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_contentdocument.htm). These are typically stored using the `PathOnClient` field which in your case should point to the location of the attachment. Depending on how this was implemented, it's also possible that they used the `TagCsv` field to somehow provide a reference to the parent or Opportunity in general. In any case, that's how I would recommend you approach investigating for how this was done in your client's org.

Visually, you'll find three different data models that should be helpful to you in the SOAP Developer Guide one for [Document, Note, and Attachment Objects](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_erd_documents.htm), another for [Content Objects](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_erd_content.htm) and finally one for [ContentNote Objects](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_erd_contentnote.htm). The first is clearly not what was implemented. Something that's a variation which included parts of the latter two would be I'd expect you'd want to look for.